# Setting drive spindown time on megacli

Tags: linux, megaraid

I'm having trouble setting the spindown time on MegaRaid using MegaCLI. Apparently, I'm doing something wrong - in essence, I'd like to set default spindown time for all disks.

I'm trying this:

`megacli -AdpSetProp -SpinDownTime 0 -a0`

And this is what I get:

```
Adapter 0: Spin Down of UnConfigured drive option is not supported.
Adapter 0: Failed to Set Adapter Properties.
```

So, how can I change the default spindown time?
It's currently (by default) set to 30 min:

```
megacli -AdpAllInfo -aAll | grep spin
Maximum number of direct attached drives to spin up in 1 min : 20 
Default spin down time in minutes: 30
```